# Logging configuration for certain EJB Jar on JBoss Server

Tags: logging, jboss, jar, log4j

can you specify on JBoss server logging level for single EJB Jar? I've got two EJB Jars with two different Web Services. I would like the WS logs from first jar to be printed completely to server log file whereas WS logs from second jar are irrevelant and i don't want them printed anywhere. Can it be configured on JBoss?

I'm using log4j logger.

Comment: Are you referring to logging statements from the application code in each JAR, or logging calls from JBoss's plumbing?

Comment: I am refering to logging call from JBoss's plumbing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss comes with a logging filter called `TCLFilter` that allows you to filter appenders by the deployment that generated them.  See [this page](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/SeparatingApplicationLogs) for how to use it.

Depennding on how you deploy your EJB JARs, this may or may not work. If they're all in one EAR, then I think you're out of luck, unless you can configure the `TCLFilter` to specify the individual EJB JAR within the EAR. If the EJB JARs are deployed on their own, then `TCLFilter` should be fairly easy to get working.